# Adding RichTextBlockOverflow to FlipView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, richtextblock, flipview

I have a book application that I am using the `FlipView` control to flip between pages of any selected chapter in the book the user is currently reading.

I am dynamically creating the pages in and adding them as items in the `FlipView` control with the following code:

```
    private void CreateNewFlipPage(RichTextBlockOverflow columnContent, int page)
    {
        var fvItem = new FlipViewItem();
        var grid = GetOverflowGrid();   // Pre-formatted grid with 4 columns (index 0, 2, 4, and 6) and three 30 pixel spacer columns in between (index 1, 3, and 5)

        var overFlow1 = new RichTextBlockOverflow();
        var overFlow2 = new RichTextBlockOverflow();
        var overFlow3 = new RichTextBlockOverflow();
        var overFlow4 = new RichTextBlockOverflow();
        var pageText = new TextBlock
        {
            VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
            Opacity = 0.5,
            FontSize = 18.667,
            Margin = new Thickness(40, 0, 0, 0),
            Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationPageTextOppositeBackgroundThemeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush,
            FontFamily = new FontFamily("Global User Interface"),
            Text = "Page " + page
        };

        overFlow4.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 40);

        Grid.SetColumn(overFlow1, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(overFlow2, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(overFlow3, 4);
        Grid.SetColumn(overFlow4, 6);
        Grid.SetColumn(pageText, 6);

        grid.Children.Add(overFlow1);
        grid.Children.Add(overFlow2);
        grid.Children.Add(overFlow3);
        grid.Children.Add(overFlow4);
        grid.Children.Add(pageText);

        fvItem.Content = grid;
        FlipView.Items.Add(fvItem);

        overFlow1.OverflowContentTarget = columnContent;
        overFlow2.OverflowContentTarget = overFlow1;
        overFlow3.OverflowContentTarget = overFlow2;
        overFlow4.OverflowContentTarget = overFlow3;

        overFlow1.Measure(new Size(grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth, grid.ActualHeight));
        overFlow2.Measure(new Size(grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth, grid.ActualHeight));
        overFlow3.Measure(new Size(grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth, grid.ActualHeight));
        overFlow4.Measure(new Size(grid.ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth, grid.ActualHeight));

        grid.UpdateLayout();

        if (overFlow4.HasOverflowContent)
        {
            CreateNewFlipPage(overFlow4, page++);
        }
    }
```

And I call this code in my Initial UI method here once the UI has been updated:

```
...
if (column4Content.HasOverflowContent)
{
    CreateNewFlipPage(column4Content, 2);  // column4Content is a RTBO object
}
...
```

If I don't call the last part, I get the first full page and nothing else.
If I do call the last part, I get the first 3 columns on the first page and an item is added to `FlipView`, but no text is shown on the second page and the 4th column disappears

What am I not doing to make all of the RTBO objects to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have **Update** your FlipView **Layout** too. In this way the **HasOverflowContent** property knows that it has any overflow contents or not and returns it's true value (whether true or false).

```
grid.UpdateLayout();

FlipView.UpdateLayout(); // Add this Line Here

if (column4Content.HasOverflowContent)
{
    CreateNewFlipPage(column4Content, 2);
}
```

But I have doubts about the performance. Read the **UpdateLayout()** document here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.updatelayout

> ... Layout updates can be forced by app code rather than relying on the
>   built-in layout system behavior by using the **UpdateLayout** method.
>   However, that is not generally recommended. It is usually unnecessary
>   and can cause poor performance if overused. ...